# Calling Java from CLI vs. by PHP exec

Tags: java, php, out-of-memory, exec

so I'm using MPEG7 library to extract audio descriptors from a .wav file.

When I run in CLI

```
java -jar  MPEG7AudioEnc.jar audio/audio.wav > xml/audio.xml
```

everything runs flawlessly. However, when I want to call this exact thing from PHP by exec

```
<?php exec("java -jar  MPEG7AudioEnc.jar audio/audio.wav > xml/audio.xml" ); ?>
```

I'm getting a java.lang.outOfMemorError due to not enough Java heap space (output should be around 50-100MBs). I don't really understand how are these cases different and how to fix it?

Thanks
Michal

Comment: It might be the PHP memory allowances which need to be set higher since the Java settings are used from the default settings. Look in your php.ini (the correct one, can be multiple) for `memory_limit` and set it to at least `512M`

Comment: That was a first thing I have done, I set all the limits in php.ini to 512M, as well as i set all the time limits higher

Comment: Try `java -Xmx256M` in both the CLI test and the exec. And increase the PHP limit higher to `1024`. The limit has to contain both the memory for the java executable, the memory java uses for executing the code and the memory of php itself. You might be able to make an educated guess by checking how much memory the CLI call takes and set a limit from there. Also check any other running PHP code on in code memory limit overrides.

Comment: Oh cool, setting heap size to 512M helped. Thanks a lot! However, just for being curious, I still don't understand why are these heap sizes different by default for exec and CLI calls?

Comment: There are default memory settings in the Java executable which are based on the amount of system memory available. If there is less memory available, the executable chooses a smaller setting. The memory available is configured by the environment it is started in, in this case PHP with 512M, which is then considered small, after which the Java executable chooses to use a smaller memory footprint to avoid not being able to start/extreme slow down of the system. As you notice: It does not always work as designed.